# How to have multiple FAQs(KBs) with same questions but different answers?

Tags: azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I am unable to keep the context(FAQ) of the chatbot conversation.

I have successfully integrated LUIS+QnAmaker based on this documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/tutorials/integrate-qnamaker-luis

I have about 3 KBs that contain the same questions but different answers. The chatbot should be able to filter to the desired FAQ and the following answers should be from the chosen FAQ from the user. Currently, it only returns the first KB for the answers unless I phrase my question this way:
Can I have the answer for FAQ1? or
Can I have the answer for FAQ2?

Hope I can have some help from the community here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you are using multiple KBs with same questions, you can segregate the answers by adding different metadata to your question/answer sets. A metadata is just a collection of name / value pairs. When using the QnAMakerDialog, you have the ability to set either [filtering or boosting metadata](https://github.com/garypretty/botframework/tree/master/QnAMakerDialog#boosting-and-filtering-answers-using-metadata), which will be passed as part of any queries to the QnA Maker Service.

You can create your QnA Maker dialog and add a single name / value metadata pair to the MetadataFilter property on the dialog. This will then cause the dialog to only receive answers marked with the same name / value metadata.

MessagesController:

```
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    internal static IDialog<object> MakeRoot()
    {
        var qnaDialog = new Dialogs.MyQnADialog
        {
            MetadataFilter = new List<Metadata>()
            {
                new Metadata()
                {
                    Name = "knowledgeBase",
                    Value = "kb1"

                }
            }
        };

        return qnaDialog;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// POST: api/Messages
    /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
    /// </summary>
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, MakeRoot);
        }
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }

}
```

Similarly, if you want to use the other knowledge base, you can pass the other metadata name/value pairs.e.g, { Name="knowledgeBase",Value="kb2" }

QnAMAkerDialog:

```
[QnAMakerService("https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker/", "{EndpointKey_here}", "{KnowledgeBaseId_here}",1)]
public class MyQnADialog : QnAMakerDialog<object>
{
    public override async Task NoMatchHandler(IDialogContext context, string originalQueryText)
    {
        await context.PostAsync($"Sorry, I couldn't find an answer for '{originalQueryText}'.");
        context.Done(false);
    }

    public override async Task DefaultMatchHandler(IDialogContext context, string originalQueryText, QnAMakerResult result)
    {
        if (result.Answers.FirstOrDefault().Score > 80)
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"I found {result.Answers.Length} answer(s) that might help...{result.Answers.First().Answer}.");
        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"Sorry, I couldn't find an answer for '{originalQueryText}'.");
        }

        context.Done(true);
    }
}
```

Example :
Metadata tagging
[image]

When you test it, the result will be as follows:

- With knowledgeBase:kb1

[image]

- With knowledgeBase:kb2

[image]

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thanks for replying to my question. The solution that you have provided, is it meant to be used on a single chatbot? My desired solution is to use a single chatbot, where the user will decide which KB to enquire at the start.

Comment: Yes, it is for a single chatbot. The above solution is one of the ways to filter or segregate the answers by source. The user is selecting which KB to use by passing the name/value metadata pair  to the MetadataFilter property on the dialog.

Comment: What I do not understand is, why is the value metadata written in the code? Shouldn't it be dynamic as it will change depending on what the user inputs in the chatbot?